# rpy2 unable to load shared object when import package of stats from R

Tags: python, r, rpy2

Operation system: windows XP

Python version: 3.4.3

R version: 3.3.0

rpy2 version: 2.7.8 from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

[picture of running message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SLSH.png)

As showed in the picture, the rpy2 package has been installed successfully and some packages of R, like base, tools, can be imported. However, the stats package can not as described by the errors message.

Does anyone have point about this? thanks a lot.

Comment: In fact, the stats package can be loaded in R, I can use it to perform analysis but it just can not be imported by rpy2.

Comment: Works for me. Maybe try to add your `R\bin\i386` directory to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: It does work. Many thanks for your help, cgohlke, :)